# In a GitLab CICD pipeline, how do I skip a job if changes are exclusive to specific directories?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Let's say I have the following repository and my CICD pipeline has separate build jobs for App1, App2, and App3. I want the jobs to run according to the following rules:

1. I *don't* want the App1 build job to run if all changes were *only* made in App2/ or App3/ directories. Similarly, I don't want the App1 build job to run if all changes were *only* made in App2/ or App3/ directories.
2. I want all jobs to run if changes are made outside of the app-specific directories. For example, changes in any Common directory should result in all apps building.

```
App1/
App2/
App3/
Common1/
Common2/
Common3/
.gitlab-ci.yml
```

**Question:** How can I specify that the App1 job should run only if ALL changes are NOT in the App2 and App3 directories? From looking at the `rules:changes` options, I'm not sure if this is possible. I know that I *could* specify the App1 job to run if changes are made in App1/ or Common1/ or Common2/ or Common3/, but I'd rather not have to update the script if we add a Common4/. In other words: *I want to skip my App1 job if latest changes are exclusive to the other apps (App2 and App3)*.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use `rules:changes` along with `when:never` to skip the job when the rule is `true` :

```yaml
build_app1:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Building App1"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
      changes:
        - "App2/**/*"
        - "App3/**/*"
      when: never
```

As the documentation mentions, `rules:changes` should be used only with branch pipelines and merge request pipelines.

Tag pipelines, scheduled pipelines, manual pipelines, and so on do not have a Git push event associated with them, so `rules:changes` always evaluates to true.

Comment: Thanks for the input! However, if I understand correctly, this would skip building App1 if changes include App2/ and App3/. I want App1 to be skipped only if all changes are in App2/ and App3/. For example, if a push includes changes to Common1/ and App2/, I still want App1 to build. But if changes are only to App2/, then I don't want App1 to build.